# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, utf-8

I getting this error

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 69: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

on this line of code: `documents1 = text_file.read().split("\n\n")`.  I am opening the file with `text_file = open(filepath, "r")`

Normally I would simply stick `.encode('utf-8')`, but that just gives

> 'str' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: You have to *decode*, ie. use `.decode('utf-8')`. Like you would *de*crypt a file you want to read. You *en*code (or *en*crypt) when you want to send a file or write it to disk etc.

Comment: The Zen of Python says "Explicit is better than implicit." I think that this means you should always open text files with explicit encoding (as suggested by Filipe), rather than letting some unreliable locale settings decide which encoding is used.

Comment: I have tried including `encoding="utf-8"` and it made no difference

Comment: That would mean that your Python installation is broken. Or cursed. Or both.

Comment: I realised, eventually, I had the error in a couple of places - it was fixed and had moved on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by your locale settings. If it's set to UTF-8, then this should work as expected in your Python script.

Try this command to see the charmap in your setup:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

If you get something else in the output (like `ISO-8859-1` or `ANSI_X3.4-1968`) then it means you're not correctly set up for UTF-8... You can try to set environment variable `LC_CTYPE` to something like `en_US.UTF-8` (assuming English is your language), which might fix this.

Inside Python, you can also force a default encoding with:

```
text_file = open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

But it's possible you're going to find other encoding problems if your system is not correctly set up for it... So try to fix that first, if you can.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Filipe, `locale charmap` give `UTF-8` response

Comment: It also runs fine on my PC with the same file

Comment: I hadn't realised this worked and repeated the error later in the file - thanks